# Can't find correct way to select data in a CommonTableExpression with jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, common-table-expression, jooq

I am using jOOQ CommonTableExpression to get a list of distinct weekending dates from a table. It's the shortest cte in a larger query using several cte's. I have the query working in postgres but haven't got it right in jOOQ.

Per the jOOQ manual page for **WITH**:

```java
    // Code for creating a CommonTableExpression instance
    name("t1").fields("f1", "f2").as(select(val(1), val("a")));
```

I have tried:

```java
    import org.jooq.DSL.select;

    MyLog lg = MY_LOG.as("lg"); // a table generated by jOOQ.

    CommonTableExpression cteWkend = name("cteWkend")
            .fields("wkend")
            .as(select((lg.WKEND)).distinctOn(lg.WKEND).from(lg).fetch());
```

Am getting this error from intelliJ:

> as Select<R> in DerivedColumnList1 cannot be applied to  org.jooq.Result<org.jooq.Record1<LocalDate>>

It looks like the problem is within .as(select ...) and that I've got mismatching types between the (select ...) and the .as() which is expecting something different.

Searches have led me back to the jOOQ WITH manual page quoted which gives a fairly trivial example. I haven't been able to find a non-trivial example that shows me what should go there and what I am doing wrong or why it is wrong.

Can someone please point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this `fetch()` call here:

```
CommonTableExpression cteWkend = name("cteWkend")
        .fields("wkend")
        .as(select((lg.WKEND)).distinctOn(lg.WKEND).from(lg) /* .fetch() */);
```

You don't want that subquery in common table expression to be executed prior to passing its results to the common table expression

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I found I had change the .distinctOn call in the last line to: `.as(selectDistinct(lg.WKEND).from(lg) )`